# The associated entity manager is closed! Hibernate envers

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-envers

I am using Hibernate envers trying to retrieve audit records from Audit table, but seeing exception 
The associated entity manager is closed! Hibernate envers. Here is the code which is giving the exception.

```
public void returnUserAudit(){
        AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);
        return auditReader.createQuery().forRevisionsOfEntity(UserDetails.class, true, true)
                .add(AuditEntity.property("userDetails.userId").eq(appId)).
                add(AuditEntity.property("userDetails.email").eq(deplymntId)).
                add(AuditEntity.property("status").eq("Approved")).
                addOrder(AuditEntity.revisionNumber().desc()).
                setMaxResults(recordLimit).getResultList();
}

java.lang.IllegalStateException: The associated entity manager is closed!
at org.hibernate.envers.internal.reader.AuditReaderImpl.checkSession(AuditReaderImpl.java:65) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.envers.internal.reader.AuditReaderImpl.isEntityNameAudited(AuditReaderImpl.java:306) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.envers.query.AuditQueryCreator.checkEntityAudited(AuditQueryCreator.java:346) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
at org.hibernate.envers.query.AuditQueryCreator.forRevisionsOfEntity(AuditQueryCreator.java:169) ~[hibernate-envers-5.3.10.Final.jar!/:5.3.10.Final]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check your usage pattern for `entityManager`.  You are either caching an instance of an open EM at some point and attempting to reuse it after its since been closed or the instance was never properly opened in the first place.  In either case, this is indicative of a user error and not one with Envers.